# jQueryでのスクロールイベント中にanimateを止めたい

Tags: jquery

jQueryでスクロール位置によってコンテンツを表示させています。
その中で、表示後にその中の画像の位置を変更してアニメーションさせている部分があるのですが、スクロールごとに何度も動いてしまいます(1回だけで止めたい)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#box1').each(function() {
        var boxPos = $(this).offset().top;
        if(scroll > boxPos - windowHeight + 300){
            $(this).find('.transparence').animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, 600);
            $(this).find('.textarea').delay(400).animate({
                'opacity': '1',
            }, 600, function() {
                $('#moveimg01').delay('200').animate({
                    'left': '270px',
                    'bottom': '20px'
                }, 300, function() {
                    $('#moveimg01').animate({
                        'left': '250px',
                        'bottom': '0'
                    }, 200);
                });
            });
        }
    });
    $('#box2').each(function() {
        var boxPos = $(this).offset().top;
        if(scroll > boxPos - windowHeight + 300){
            $(this).find('.transparence').animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, 600, function() {
                $('#moveimg02').delay(200).animate({
                    'right': '-20px',
                    'top': '40px'
                }, 300, function() {
                    $('#moveimg02').animate({
                        'right': '0',
                        'top': '60px'
                    }, 200);
                });
            });
            $(this).find('.textarea').delay(400).animate({
                'opacity': '1',
            }, 600);
        }
    }); ・・・続く
```

この最後の

```
$('#moveimg01').animate({
  'left': '250px',
  'bottom': '0'
}, 200);
```

の部分でそれぞれ止めたいのですが、スクロールするたびに何度も動いてしまいます。
この部分で止める方法、もっとほかの書き方などありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

画面内の要素位置をスクロールするたびに記録しておき
($(anim要素).offset().top + $(anim要素).outerHeight()) - $(window).scrollTop()がマイナス値 -> プラス値になったとき
または
$(anim要素).offset().top - ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())がプラス値 ->
マイナス値になったとき
にアニメーションさせればいいんでないでしょうか。

前の要素位置は$(anim要素).data('before', beforePos);で要素ごとにセットしておけばいいかと

Answer (score 0):

JSで各要素の状態を保持しておく方法もあると思いますが、
自分がよくとる方法は、htmlのclassで状態を管理してJSで判別するやり方です。

`#moveimg01`要素に`.toAnimate`等のクラスをつけておいて、

```
$('#box1').hasClass('toAnimate').each(function() {
    var boxPos = $(this).offset().top;
    if(scroll > boxPos - windowHeight + 300){
        $('#box1').removeClass('toAnimate') // ここでクラスを消します
        // ... 省略 ...
            }, 300, function() {
                $('#moveimg01').animate({
                    'left': '250px',
                    'bottom': '0'
                }, 200);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

などと記述すれば、一度アニメーションした後はアニメーションしなくなるかと思います。

```
$('#box1.toAnimate').each(
```

でもよいですね。

似たやり方で、動いた要素に`.isAnimated`などのクラスを付与して、
クラスを持っていたら処理をさせない、というやり方もあるかと思います。

---

質問とは関係ないですがコードに気になった点があったので書きます。

1. `$('#box1').each(...`など同IDのを持つ要素は存在しないはずなのに `.each()`を使っている

   => この部分 each() である必要ありますか？確認してみてください。
2. `$('#moveimg01')`など同要素を複数回取得している

   => 取得回数（要素の検索回数）が多くなる = 処理が遅くなる ですので、

   ```
   var $target = $('#moveimg01');
   $target.delay('200').animate({
       // ... 省略 ...
   }, 300, function() {
       $target.animate({
           // ... 省略 ...
       }, 200);
   });
   ```

   みたいに書くといいですよ。